# How to format mobile phone number with country code using regex

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have been trying to format properly the phone number so that all country can use at least. I am trying to use this format to accept as many regions as possible
Here is my pattern

```
$pattern = '^\+[0-9]?()[0-9](\s|\S)(\d[0-9]{9})$^';
```

the pattern matches well these formats but once I add a country code with 3 digits and space, it
fails

```
+441213315000
+1 2323214316
+2923432432432
```

I would like to match this format

```
+225 0546568022
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
^\+[0-9]{1,3} ?[0-9]{10}$
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/aUKyoG/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \+                       '+'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]{1,3}               any character of: '0' to '9' (between 1
                           and 3 times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ?                       ' ' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]{10}                any character of: '0' to '9' (10 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

PHP:

```php
preg_match('/^\+[0-9]{1,3} ?[0-9]{10}$/', $string)
```

JavaScript:

```js
/^\+[0-9]{1,3} ?[0-9]{10}$/.test(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike our friend. I tried to fix your own pattern:

```
^\+([0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?)(\ )?([0-9]{10})$
```

Note that i've removed the ^ from end of pattern because it represents start of a new line!

This guy is your friend: https://regex101.com/

Good luck

Comment: Note that to get a match only you can omit the capture groups, you don't have to escape the space and matching 1-3 digits can be shortened to `[0-9]{1,3}` like `^\+[0-9]{1,3} ?[0-9]{10}$` See https://regex101.com/r/2zxwZo/1

Comment: Yeah you're right. But i've been trying to solve this by his/her own knowledge